# I don't know / group by ? having ? subquery? what can I use?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, having

```
select seq from a where link != 1
```

---

```
seq | link
1   | 1
1   | 0
2   | 0
3   | 1
4   | 0
```

I want return seq not in 1 : 2, 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT seq
  FROM a
 GROUP BY seq
HAVING SUM(link = 1) = 0;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cec31/1/0)